# Subdomain masking

Tags: php, .htaccess, cross-domain, subdomain

I want to know is it possible to mask our subdomain to another domain.
e.g:
this is may doamin :   mydomain1.com   so my subdomain is : sub.mydomain1.com

so how could i transfer mask sub.mydomain1.com with any other domain e.d facebook.com

so when someone open sub.mydomain1.com it show sub.mydomain1.com in address bar but show contects of facebook.

i don't want to do this with php because that will use all of my bandwidth because i want to stream videos so i can't also use iframe .

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do that with a HEADER-redirect. Mostly, you can set one in the admin-panel of your domain service provider.

If you do it with javascript, the url in the browser would change.

Comment: for may admin panel ther isn't any option . and about javascript or header-redirect can you provide me code ?